# как передать в конструктор контроллера объект

Tags: php, symfony3

Например, я создаю несколько классов для валидации, которые наследуются от одного абстрактного класса, в котором есть конструктор. В конструктор мне надо передать сервис контейнер. В контроллер я передаю валидатор так:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    AdminBundle\:
        resource: '../../*'
        exclude: '../../{Entity,Repository}'
```

Но мне надо передать сервис контейнер в этот клас:

```
abstract class BaseValidation
{
    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    protected $container;

    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface
     */
    protected $validator;

    /**
     * AuthValidation constructor.
     * @param Container $container
     */
    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest();
        $this->validator = Validation::createValidator();
    }

    /**
     * @param $constraints
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getViolations($constraints)
    {
        $requestArray = [];
        foreach ($constraints->fields as $key => $constraint) {
            $requestArray[$key] = $this->request->get($key);
        }
        return $this->validator->validate($requestArray, $constraints);
    }

    /**
     * @param $constraints
     * @return array
     */
    protected function returnErrors($constraints): array
    {
        $violations = $this->getViolations($constraints);
        $errors = [];
        if (0 !== \count($violations)) {
            foreach ($violations as $error) {
                $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $errors;
    }

}
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: обычно не рекомендуют передавать в конструктор сразу контейнер. Лучше передавать сами сервисы-реализации, а в конструкторе требовать интерфейсы.

Comment: А как так сделать? Например мне нужен сервис контейнер в классе BaseValidation, а в каждом конкретном контроллере - класс, наследуемый от BaseValidation

Comment: Если предположить, что все наследники `BaseValidation` имеют единый интерфейс, то можно реализовать фабрику валидаторов, которая возвращает этот интерфейс, а, в реализации, необходимый валидатор (например по каноническому имени). Тогда интерфейс этой фабрики можно требовать в конструкторе каждого контроллера, а инъектить эту фабрику в контроллер из сервис-контейнера через обычный конфиг

Comment: И небольшой уточняющий вопрос: `Container` в валидаторе - это обычный симфонячий сервис-контейнер или что-то свое?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае будет примерно так (с точностью до путей)

```
AdminBundle\BaseValidation:
    arguments:
        - '@container'
    abstract: true
```

Comment: нет, ответ неправильный, я написал пример конфига, он передает нужный мне обьект в конструктор контроллера, теперь вопрос как передать нужный обьект в конструктор класса валидации

Comment: В Вашем конфиге включен автовайринг для всех ресурсов модуля кроме Entity и Repository. Т.е. все прочие объекты считаются сервисам и в них (при наличии конструктора) пытаются заинъектиться соответствующие сервисы. В моем конфиге происходит инъекция вручную (просто альтернатива), но это как мне кажется правильнее, учитывая, что класс абстрактный